# from django.db.models.Value not including quotes when converting to query string

Tags: sqlite, django-models, concatenation, coalesce

I am using the `django.db.models.Value` expression within a QuerySet function in Django 3.2.8. When passing a string value (`"|"` in my example below), the conversion to a query string fails to add the `'`, which makes the query to fail.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
    

qs = PurchaseOrder.objects.annotate(
    concat=Concat(
        F("customer_name"),
        Value("~"),
        F("date"),
        output_field=models.CharField(),
    )
).values("concat")
```

```
>>> print(str(qs.query))
SELECT CONCAT("purchaseorder"."customer_name", CONCAT(~, "purchaseorder"."date")) AS "concat" FROM "purchaseorder"
```

As it can be seen from the result above, the `~` character  is missing the two `'` it should be wrapped around: `CONCAT('~', "purchaseorder"."date")`.

Is this the expected functionality of expression `Value` or a bug that should be reported?
I am inclined to think it is a bug, because of the following:

I initially solved the problem above by writing it as `Value("'~'")`, with the two `'` inside my string. However, when running the query in a sqlite3 database during unit testing I got an error in the query. I realised that sqlite has a different syntax than Postgres (my production and local dev database) for function Contact:

- Postgres: `CONCAT([args])`
- Sqlite: `arg1 || arg2 ...`

In the sqlite case, Django also wraps every argument in the concatenation with `Coalesce`:

```
COALESCE(arg1, '') || COALESCE(arg2, '')
```

The query that was resulting from this in sqlite looked like the one below:

```
... COALESCE("purchaseorder"."customer_name", ) || COALESCE('~', ) || COALESCE("purchaseorder"."date",)
```

(Note that I passed `'` inside `Value("'~'")` this time)

The above query will give an error as the second argument inside `COALESCE` must not be empty (`''` is an acceptable input).

If the above problem is due to a bug, what would be the best workaround to make the sqlite query work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug:

Inside `django.db.models.functions.text.ConcatPair`, method `as_sqlite` calls method `coalesce`:

```
class ConcatPair(Func):
    ...

    def as_sqlite(self, compiler, connection, **extra_context):
        coalesced = self.coalesce()
        return super(ConcatPair, coalesced).as_sql(
            compiler, connection, template='%(expressions)s', arg_joiner=' || ',
            **extra_context
        )

    ...

    def coalesce(self):
        # null on either side results in null for expression, wrap with coalesce
        c = self.copy()
        c.set_source_expressions([
            Coalesce(expression, Value('')) for expression in c.get_source_expressions()
        ])
        return c
```

This is the mechanism that wraps the arguments inside the concatenation with the COALESCE function, and as it can be seen, it is using `Value('')`. This means that expression `Value` is meant to be used directly with a string, as the expression above is expected to produce `COALESCE([expression], '')` in SQL.

I have not yet figured out what the exact problem is within `Value`, but below is a workaround for the `COALESCE` problem inside the concatenation. Simply override the `coalesce` method inside `ConcatPair`, adding `'` inside `Value`:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ConcatPair, Coalesce


def _coalesce(self):
    c = self.copy()
    c.set_source_expressions(
        [Coalesce(expression, Value("''")) for expression in c.get_source_expressions()]
    )
    return c


ConcatPair.coalesce = _coalesce
```